# Node.js out of memory when running a large Jest test suite

Tags: node.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I’m running a large test suite with Jest (`26.6.2`) and react-testing-library (`12.1.2`) on Node.js (`16.3.1`).

At some point the test suite *sometimes* crashes with

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

The first idea is that the Node.js heap is full. Thus, I’ve set a heap size of 2GB via `--max-old-space-size=2048` and also enabled GC logging (Node’s `--expose-gc` + Jest’s `--logHeapUsage`).
The GC logging indicates that **the heap space is probably *not* the problem** (if my understanding is correct, the error message is at least misleading):

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[206149:0x4b56570]  1113100 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 872.1 (1175.1) -> 871.2 (1114.6) MB, 1786.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.018, current mu = 0.014) last resort GC in old space requested
[206149:0x4b56570]  1114841 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 871.2 (1114.6) -> 871.2 (1091.4) MB, 1740.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.009, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
  1: 0xb00d90 node::Abort() [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  2: 0xa1823b node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  3: 0xcedbce v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  4: 0xcedf47 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  5: 0xea6105  [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  6: 0xeb8588 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  7: 0xe85b76 v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::AllocateCode(bool) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  8: 0xe86885 v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::BuildInternal(bool) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
  9: 0xe8729e v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::Build() [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 10: 0x14d69fe v8::internal::RegExpMacroAssemblerX64::GetCode(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 11: 0x11c1329 v8::internal::RegExpCompiler::Assemble(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::RegExpMacroAssembler*, v8::internal::RegExpNode*, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 12: 0x11df6b7 v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Compile(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::RegExpCompileData*, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::JSRegExp::Flag, int>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool, unsigned int&) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 13: 0x11dfe60 v8::internal::RegExpImpl::CompileIrregexp(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 14: 0x11e0a5e v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpPrepare(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 15: 0x11e0bd7 v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::RegExpMatchInfo>, v8::internal::RegExp::ExecQuirks) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 16: 0x1205da8 v8::internal::Runtime_RegExpExec(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
 17: 0x15e7819  [./.gradle/nodejs/node-v16.13.1-linux-x64/bin/node]
```

The tests crash at different points (even different test classes!) but I always see a `RegExp` compilation in the JS stacktrace. Searching for the stacktrace pattern leads me to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=10441#c5 which gives the hint that the V8 `code_space` memory region could be the problem:

> V8 has limit of 128*MB for code objects. Each RegExp.exec (or String.match) compiles an expression and thus creates a code object, which may be large depending on the RegExp.

Indeed, when I add logging of the V8 heap space statistics via `v8.getHeapSpaceStatistics()`, I can see that the `code_space` region *could* be causing the crashes.
The last output I see before the crash is:

```
Heap statistics: {
    "total_heap_size": 1251897344,
    "total_heap_size_executable": 133742592,
    "total_physical_size": 1249687440,
    "total_available_size": 1200419000,
    "used_heap_size": 968511640,
    "heap_size_limit": 2197815296,
    "malloced_memory": 4202568,
    "peak_malloced_memory": 12083656,
    "does_zap_garbage": 0,
    "number_of_native_contexts": 3,
    "number_of_detached_contexts": 0
}
Heap space statistics: [
    […]
    {
        "space_name": "old_space",
        "space_size": 1011437568,
        "space_used_size": 766010912,
        "space_available_size": 226275256,
        "physical_space_size": 1011428824
    },
    {
        "space_name": "code_space",
        "space_size": 133275648,
        "space_used_size": 124423840,
        "space_available_size": 512352,
        "physical_space_size": 131074880
    },
    […]
]
```

I’m wondering if the crash suggests that the test suite is just too large or if it is rather a memory leak?

Is there a way to increase the `code_space` region size in V8?

I’m appreciating any hint to narrow down the root cause for those crashes.

Comment: What does happen if you run the test suite one test a time? My first guess would be that you have a single runaway RegExp - they are compiled to a graph and maybe yours is next to impossible to evaluate

Comment: @mmomtchev: Thanks for your hint! I’ve slightly updated my question and mentioned, that my tests do not always crash and if they crash, it happens even at different test classes.
Due to that observation I didn’t follow the idea consequently enough to run the tests really separated. I’ll do that now since it could help to narrow the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the out-of-memory crash when I run the tests one at a time. OTH running the tests one at a time is a workaround for me.

Comment: Try to replace `RegExp.prototype.exec` with your own function that outputs the RegExp to the console and then calls the original one

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the out of memory crash either, when I monkey patch `RegExp.prototype.exec`.

Comment: Any updates on your outcome? I've got a similar problem.

Comment: I wasn’t able to solve it so I worked around it by executing the tests in separate processes. I’m using Gradle to dynamically create tasks where each task executes a new Node.js process that runs a single Jest test file. I’m actually quite happy with the solution to use Gradle on top of npm also for other parts of the build. Maybe could be worth a blog post if others are interested.